# How to delete or get SSH Public keys from Google Compute instances using OS Login API

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, google-iam

I have a google compute engine instance with the default service account in the form of `<project-number>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`. I can connect via SSH to my compute instance using my own pair of generated SSH keys. I followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/service-account-ssh#sa_ssh_external) where I use a slightly modified version of the [service_account_ssh.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/compute/oslogin/service_account_ssh.py) script.

This works as expected. With the line `oslogin.users().importSshPublicKey(parent=account, body=body).execute()` from the script I could add my public key. This enables me to simply SSH into the compute instance like so:
`ssh -i <private-key> <user>@<compute-instance-ip>`
Note that I do not use an expire time for the SSH key and neither delete them after generation as the example script does.

However, I am unable to delete the public key from the service account. According to the [OS Login API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/rest/v1/users.sshPublicKeys/delete), there is a `users.sshPublicKeys.delete` method, but I can't get it to work.

The first problem I ran into is that I cannot find the Python reference OS Login API. With the `service_account_ssh.py` script as example, and the OS Login API, I was able to derive the Python method: `oslogin.users().sshPublicKeys().delete(name=key).execute()`

But now I'm stuck on the `name` field. According to the docs the `name` parameter should be the fingerprint of the public key in the format `users/{user}/sshPublicKeys/{fingerprint}`

No matter what I try, I get the Python error:
`TypeError: Parameter "name" value "users/<project-number>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com/sshPublicKeys/<key-fingerprint>" does not match the pattern "^users/[^/]+/sshPublicKeys/[^/]+$"`. For security reasons I removed my actual values and replaced them with `<project-number>` and `<key-fingerprint>`

I generate my key fingerprint with `ssh-keygen -lf <key>.pub`, which outputs something in the form of `SHA256:sadlkf43jqweIFND123oifja/sdflk3234j`

Since I'm not that good with regex I used https://regexr.com/ to test my string against `^users/[^/]+/sshPublicKeys/[^/]+$`. It appears the regex does not match on the key fingerprint because there is a forward slash `/` in the fingerprint of my key. If I remove this `/` the regex matches and my python script does not throw an error, however, now the key fingerprint is invalid.

I did a quick check with a bunch of other SSH keys and they all have a forward slash somewhere in their fingerprint. But now I don't understand how I can possibly call the API with the correct string. This is the exact point where I'm stuck and I hope someone can help me.

My question is: How can I delete (or get) my SSH key in Python using the OS Login API?

Comment: Are you escaping the special characters?
The ` \ ` is considered an special character in Python, you can use the backslash to [escape](https://www.pitt.edu/~naraehan/python3/mbb6.html#:~:text=In%20Python%20strings%2C%20the%20backslash,r%22%20is%20a%20carriage%20return.) the backslash in your key fingerprint leaving them like ` \\ `

Comment: @JoséSoní Yes, I have tried escaping the forward slash in the fingerprint with a backslash like ` \/ `, but this does not seem to work for the regex, as it still does not match and Python will throw the same error.

Comment: Try using https://regex101.com/ instead of regex to evaluate your expresion, looks like regex is the problem here. Alternativelly, you can confirm if the regular expresion mentioned in your post [^users/[^/]+/sshPublicKeys/[^/]+$] is the one you are trying to evaluate or if there's something missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to first get the user registered for the ssh key entry.
On the console you can note that the name used is the same as the pub key value (in the end of string, some cases have the hostname).

To get the name for each key, I written the code bellow:

```
from pprint import pprint

from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

# Project ID for this request.
project = '<project>'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# The name of the zone for this request.
zone = '<zone>'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

request = service.instances().list(project=project, zone=zone)
# while request is not None:
response = request.execute()

for instance in response['items']:
    for sshItems in instance['metadata']['items']:
        if sshItems['key'] == 'ssh-keys':
            sshPubKey = sshItems['value']
            sshUser = sshPubKey.split(':',1)[0]
            print(sshUser)
```

It gets the user for each ssh key for all instances that you have.
Then you can use the correctly user name in your URL.